# OnItemClickListener not working icm OnScrollListener on a ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a difficulty with a OnItemClickListener. onItemClick is not called when I also have a OnScrollListener. I narrow the problem down to:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount)
```

If in this procedure I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() the OnItemClickListener does not work.
Anybody any suggestions why, or how to get around this problem?
I but breakpoints in at both onScroll and onScrollStateChanged, but they don't seemed to be called with a touch.

```
public class ArticleListActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private long categoryId = 0;
    private List<Article> objects;
    private ArticleListAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.article_list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            if(extras.containsKey("categoryId")) categoryId = extras.getLong("categoryId");
        }

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.article_list_activity);
        iDomsAndroidApp app = ((iDomsAndroidApp) getApplicationContext());

        try {
            objects = app.getDataManager().getArticlesForCategory(categoryId, 15);
            adapter = new ArticleListAdapter(this, R.layout.article_list_cell, objects, categoryId);
            lv.setOnScrollListener(this);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(iDomsAndroidApp.TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }


    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objects.get(position).getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("articleId", objects.get(position).getId());
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {   
        if(totalCount == 0) return;

        // For the moment only add, not remove items out of view. Buffer of 5.
        int buffer = 5;

        if(adapter.getCount() + buffer < firstVisible + visibleCount){
            Log.d(iDomsAndroidApp.TAG, adapter.getCount() + " + " + buffer + " < " + firstVisible + visibleCount);
            // Get next set
            try {
                iDomsAndroidApp app = ((iDomsAndroidApp) adapter.getContext().getApplicationContext());
                List<Article> newObjects = app.getDataManager().getArticlesForCategory(categoryId, adapter.getCount(), totalCount + buffer - adapter.getCount());
                for(Article item : newObjects){
                    adapter.add(item);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(iDomsAndroidApp.TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know the reason, but I solved the issue by moving adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() into the update loop (with some other performance enhancements). Performance wise this would make sense anyway, as otherwise it would be called by each move of the view, which is not necessary. That solved the problem.